# Regex, capture 4 numbers surrounded by . or line start/end

Tags: c++, regex, wxwidgets

I'm trying to capture any 1-2 digit numbers surrounded by '.' or the beginning/end of a line.

E.G

- 1.0.4.11
- 71.11.11.11
- 0.11.0.0

Are valid and:

- 1.
- 1111
- 11.11.11.
- 01.10

are not valid

Right now I've got `(?<=\.|^)\d{1,2}]?(?=\.|$)` which will capture the numbers correctly but will also capture groups such as 11.. or 1.11.

I need to extend this regex to basically verify that it is always in the format x.x.x.x where x is 1-2 digits.

For additional information, this regex will run using the wxWidgets regex class but I believe that's the standard regex parser.

**NOTE**

For anyone using this as reference... Using wxWidgets, the wxRegex class must be constructed with the `wxRE_ADVANCED`flag as by default it uses a basic/fast implementation that does not include quantifiers(?*) which are used in this expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it less generic by specifically look for your 4 groups between start and end of string (you can remove the `\.?` if you never have `.` at the start or end):

`^\.?\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.?$`

[See in Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4JY2ri/1)

Comment: Agree. Or simplify even further with ^\.?\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2}){3}\.?$

Comment: or a bit shorter `^\.?\d\d?(?:\.\d\d?){3}\.?$`